# Hovering over tags in the selector on meta renders them unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Hovering over a tag option in the tag selector renders the tag's description unreadable, as seen in the following screenshot:

[image: hovered tag]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to argue with that :) Fixed in the next build.